# isolate rows in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, threads. I have a table, thread_participants. I am trying to isolate rows that identify with a certain thread_id and a certain thread_participants.user_id.

If, for example, thread_id = 5 matches with thread_participants.user_id = 6 AND NO OTHER thread_participants, I want to know that thread_id.

But if, for example, thread_id = 7 matches with thread_participants.user_id = 6 AND thread_participants.user_id = 9, I don't want to know that thread_id

Something like this:

```
SELECT tp.thread_id FROM thread_participants tp WHERE tp.user_id = $user_id AND tp.user_id != ANYBODY ELSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
SELECT tp.thread_id
FROM thread_participants tp
GROUP BY tp.thread_id
HAVING sum(tp.user_id = $user_id) > 0 and
       sum(tp.user_id <> $user_id) = 0;
```

The first condition counts the number of rows in the table for each thread that match the user.  The `> 0` ensures that there is at least one.

The second condition counts the number of rows for each thread that don't match the user.  The `= 0` ensures that there are none.

This use of the `having` clause is quite flexible and can be used to adapt to many conditions.

Comment: Wonderful, the only thing I changed was (tp.user_id <> = $user_id) to (tp.user_id != $user_id). I was getting an error the other way around.